# Error loading native c library Use For PDF View in Android

Tags: android, native

Hello i am trying to run the sample app from link bellow

https://github.com/pangyre/apv

it uses c libraries to read pdf file

but i am facing the following error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library pdfview2 not found
```

please tell me if there is any other settings in eclipse to use native libraries

thanks in advance

the detail log is as follows.

```
11-10 20:47:45.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(406): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 20:47:45.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(406): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

11-10 20:47:45.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(406):     at cx.hell.android.pdfview.OpenFileActivity.getPDF(OpenFileActivity.java:354)

11-10 20:47:45.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(406):     at cx.hell.android.pdfview.OpenFileActivity.startPDF(OpenFileActivity.java:327)

11-10 20:47:45.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(406):     at cx.hell.android.pdfview.OpenFileActivity.onCreate(OpenFileActivity.java:152)

11-10 20:47:45.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(406):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

11-10 20:47:45.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(406):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

11-10 20:47:45.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(406):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

11-10 20:47:45.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(406):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

11-10 20:47:45.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(406):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)

11-10 20:47:45.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(406):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

11-10 20:47:45.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(406):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

11-10 20:47:45.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(406):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

11-10 20:47:45.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(406):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

11-10 20:47:45.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(406):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

11-10 20:47:45.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(406):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

11-10 20:47:45.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(406):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

11-10 20:47:45.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(406):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

11-10 20:47:45.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(406): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library pdfview2 not found

11-10 20:47:45.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(406):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:461)

11-10 20:47:45.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(406):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
11-10 20:47:45.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(406):     at cx.hell.android.pdfview.PDF.<clinit>(PDF.java:15)

11-10 20:47:45.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(406):     ... 16 more
```

Comment: Please add the library folder into your package.build the correct java path in your eclipse platform.check your java build path

Answer (score 2):

https://www.alljoyn.org/forums/developers/unsatisfied-link-error-android-221-device-emulator#comment-745

please click the link and follow the procedure.

before that i have the same error.now i got the output.try this.there is a problem in android native compiler.

Answer (score 2):

**apv0.3dev13.tar.xz pdf viewer source code problem:

native code library coulndt not load:**

```
Thread [<3> main] (Suspended (exception UnsatisfiedLinkError))  
    Runtime.loadLibrary(String, ClassLoader) line: 489  
    System.loadLibrary(String) line: 557    
    PDF.<clinit>() line: 15 
    OpenFileActivity.getPDF() line: 442 
    OpenFileActivity.startPDF(SharedPreferences) line: 403  
    OpenFileActivity.onCreate(Bundle) line: 169 
    Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Activity, Bundle) line: 1047   
    ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2459  
    ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2512   
    ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 119 
    ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1863  
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 123 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4363    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 860  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 618 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  


Please use the link. i got the output..
https://www.alljoyn.org/forums/developers/unsatisfied-link-error-android-221-device-emulator#comment-745
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the same library in an Android app. And i got the same error.
As far as I remember the mistake was that I renamed the packages in the Java code. I also had to rename the native methods in the C code to match the new package.

Did you rename the package?

Comment: no i am using as it is bt still getting the error. strange thing is when i use the .apk from site it works fine.

Comment: is there any extra setting to use native library?

Comment: You have to use the NDK to include the native code of course. But it was a long time ago since i used the library so i cannot say what i had to do to get it running. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Open up a terminal / command prompt. Navigate to the root of your Android project. Run ndk-build.
For more information please visit http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html